# Mutual dependency of maven and java 1.7 doesn't allow installing maven with Java 1.8

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, amazon-ami

I need to have maven and Java an EC2 instance.

To install maven, I use:

```
sudo wget http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-apache-maven.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
sudo sed -i s/\$releasever/6/g /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
sudo yum install -y apache-maven
```

To install Java 1.8 I use:

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
sudo yum remove java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

And then updating the environment variables:

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64'
export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

The problem is that when I install Java 1.8 while maven is installed, maven is removed when Java 1.7 is removed, since it is a dependency of Java 1.7:

```
Removing for dependencies:
apache-maven                               noarch                   3.3.9-1.el6                                      @epel-apache-maven                   9.5 M
```

When I install Java maven while Java 1.8 is installed, Java 1.8 is replaced with Java 1.7:

```
Dependency Installed:
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 ...
```

How can I have both maven and Java 1.8 without them removing each other?

Comment: How about installing maven as exploded directory post java 8 installation?

Comment: If you like an tool to manage java and maven installation then you can try [sdkman](http://sdkman.io)

Comment: @RishikeshDarandale Can you explain what you mean by an "exploded directory", and how can I do it after the Java 8 installation?

Comment: Get the Apache maven `wget http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.5.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin.tar.gz`. then explode it in your user home directory as `tar -xvzf {file name }`. Finally add `{maven_home}/bin` to your path

Comment: Great - solved it for me. Would you like to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest below options for your answer:

- Directly get the maven bin file and explode it to use it after java 8 installation as below:

  wget http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.5.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin.tar.gz

  tar -xvzf {downloaded _maven_file} 
  // Update the path variable
- One can use [sdkman](http://sdkman.io) to manage installation of java and maven.